# Sent items appearing as drafts on Exchange 2016 (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, dns, powershell, exchange

After setting right IMAP, POP and SMTP parameters, my locally installed Exchange 2016 is still not able to send emails (nor receive) any, and when i send emails from a normal user it returns :

> "we're not ready to send your email, yet but we will soon"

warning message without actually sending the email and while keeping it in the drafts.

What might be the problem ?

PS : i was suspecting the DNS server not to be set correctly, but i have one running with the right IPv4 address (not showing in the `nslookup` cmd results though)

Thank you.

UPDATE : using the connectivity testing tool of Ms' Outlook on an email on the server it returned the following error :

```
The server response was: 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname, [13.74.35.9]
Détails de l’exception :
Message : Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname, [13.74.35.9]
Type : System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException
Arborescence des appels de procédure :
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Tools.ExRca.Tests.SmtpMessageTest.PerformTestReally()
```

Comment: what research have you done?>>>>>https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2164221-your-message-will-be-sent-we-are-not-quite-ready

Comment: I tried to be specific on the IP addresses to add for the dns lookup but still the nslookup doesn't show my server and the emails are still being stuck in draft folder

Comment: The new error message says 'Cannot find your reverse hostname.' Research that error for suggestions. Also run your domain through MX Toolbox > https://mxtoolbox.com/, which will help detail what kind of MX errors exist for your domain, and links on tips for how to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thread which has the similar undeliverable code **`4.7.1 Client host rejected...`** for your reference: **[Client host rejected](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/405712-client-host-rejected)**.

Based on the solution in the above thread, maybe the 4.7.1 issue was caused due to the lack of PTR records, therefore, view if the **PTR** record corresponding to the IP address(`13.74.35.9`) has been created in DNS.

Comment: with this it doesn't seem to be working either, it is not in the Draft anymore (it is now in the Sent) but the email is not received.